# How to use a Note 4 and its pen on a PC?

Tags: windows-10, android, screen-sharing

I have a Galaxy Note 4 which has a pen -  this is really useful for drawing. I would like very much to use this for applications on a PC (Windows 10), typically Skype for Business whiteboard and similar ones.

Is there a way to link the Android screen to a PC for such a usage?

Comment: No you cannot do that,...Buy a Wacom touch pad for working in windows....http://www.amazon.com/Wacom-Wireless-Touch-Pad-Digital-CTH300K/dp/B00EQW6M2S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there are apps out there to do this, but nothing really 'native'.  You'd have to sideload this app and I can't vouch for it's usability for what you want.

This article is 3 years old, but I think should work on the Notes with S-Pen.  [SPenDigitizer](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tablets-in-the-enterprise/use-your-samsung-galaxy-note-tablet-as-a-digitizer-for-your-pc/)